# HTML5 canvas library for touch devices

Tags: html, canvas, touch, fabricjs

I want to make custom t-shirt designer with  all touch device. I created same custom t-shirt designer with Fabric.js and some .dll file for web application that work fine for me. But I want to know if Fabric is good for all touch devices.

Fabric.js work fine for me in web application but I want to know if Fabric.js is better for touch device and supported all event of touch for all touch device like Android, iOS and windows devices? If Fabric.js is not best than suggest me another library or javascript file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

FabricJS supports touch events and has a wide variety of great features.

Nice Choice!

However, no .dll files...

.dll's are not really web-friendly — they are used for desktop OS's.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i was used lots of method of fabric in web application that i built. but can i tab and double tab event with fabricjs? i want to scale and rotate any shape in touch device so is their any method in fabric for that. if you have any demo link then please send me thanks in advance.

Comment: @Luxelin I like/use d3 in my accounting projects however I don't really see it being a good solution for a t-shirt design app.  But I'm certainly open-minded :-)  Could you code a quick mockup of a d3 t-shirt design app for us?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nothing about fabric, but if you need good js canvas libraries do you have plenty of choices.

- [Easeljs](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)
- [Kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com)
- [Paperjs](http://paperjs.org)
- [Threejs](http://threejs.org)
- [Phaser.io](http://phaser.io)

Comment: Thanks for reply but i was seen demo of this all libraries. no one has method like fabric and user can customize shape manually. are you sure anyone from that good for touch device?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric.js will be the best choice.

It supports touch events as you asked.

FYI..

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/670